# Passing filtered list in custom directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I have a list of objects, named`eventPlans`, to show in a div with some filter. Now I want to pass that filtered list, named `pendingEventPlans`, in another directive actually in my search directive.

```
<div> 
    <search-box list-to-count="pendingEventPlans" search-text="searchText" display-text="'Total event plans'"></search-box>
       <div class="has-search-with-count">
          <div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in pendingEventPlans = (eventPlans | orderBy : 'from_date'| filter:pendingFilter | filter:searchText )">
               <div>{{item.name}}</div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Then in the `search-box` directive, the list got undefined.

The actual problem is in my `ionic v1` app code. I built a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DreamRunner/1Lw38e72/) to try to simulate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `pendingEventPlans` is undefined at that point, you should do something like:

```
<div> 
<search-box list-to-count="(eventPlans | filter:pendingFilter | filter:searchText )" search-text="searchText" display-text="'Total event plans'"></search-box>
   <div class="has-search-with-count">
      <div class="list card" ng-repeat="item in pendingEventPlans = (eventPlans | orderBy : 'from_date'| filter:pendingFilter | filter:searchText )">
           <div>{{item.name}}</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```